# Grouping a range of dates in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following db, I want to group PAS_DATE for a range of 3 days, for example form 2015-03-06 to 2015-03-09

```
PAS_DATE    RED_DATE       TOT
2015-03-06  2015-03-07     2
            2015-03-17    14
            2015-12-22     1
2015-03-07  2015-03-08     3
            2015-03-19     6
            2015-10-14     2
            2015-12-07     1
2015-03-08  2015-09-16     8
2015-03-09  2015-03-09     7
            2015-03-15     6
            2015-03-18     8
            2015-04-04    15
            2015-04-12    19
            2015-05-04    44
            2015-08-17     5
            2015-09-09    13
            2015-12-06     3
            2015-12-13     3
2015-03-10  2015-03-10     7
```

The output should be :

```
PAS_DATE    RED_DATE      TOT
2015-03-09  2015-03-07     2
            2015-03-17    14
            2015-12-22     1
            2015-03-08     3
            2015-03-19     6
            2015-10-14     2
            2015-12-07     1
            2015-09-16     8
            2015-03-09     7
            2015-03-15     6
            2015-03-18     8
            2015-04-04    15
            2015-04-12    19
            2015-05-04    44
            2015-08-17     5
            2015-09-09    13
            2015-12-06     3
            2015-12-13     3
2015-03-12  2015-03-10     7
```

Is there a way to perform this code without iterations in Pandas or Python?

Comment: without iterations?  do you mean without any looping construct at all?

Comment: yes,I have a large dataset and looping constructs are slow ...

Comment: one way or another, you are going to have to iterate over the rows just to evaluate the data.   Looping is one of the core constructs of anything working on a set or programming in general.

Comment: I have tried your interesting solution but I got ITypeError for df['for_group_by'] = df.PAS_DATE + df['shift']: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<m8[ns]')

Comment: I have updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, if this is more efficient than using some loop with iterrows(), but here is a way (well, it is hacky though):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2015-01-01","2015-01-10"), columns=['PAS_DATE'])

df['dt_since_first'] = (df.PAS_DATE - df.PAS_DATE.min()).dt.days
df['shift'] = pd.to_timedelta(2 - np.mod(df.dt_since_first, 3), unit='d')
df['for_group_by'] = df.PAS_DATE + df['shift']
```

1. Create a new column that holds the
   timedelta since the first date in the column and convert it to
   integers, as number of days.
2. Now use mod3 to find, how many days PAS_DATE must be shifted to get
   to your 3 day (ceil) binning and convert it back to timedelta objects.
3. Simply shift the PAS_DATEs by this timedelta.

Here is the output:

```
    PAS_DATE  dt_since_first  shift for_group_by
0 2015-01-01               0 2 days   2015-01-03
1 2015-01-02               1 1 days   2015-01-03
2 2015-01-03               2 0 days   2015-01-03
3 2015-01-04               3 2 days   2015-01-06
4 2015-01-05               4 1 days   2015-01-06
5 2015-01-06               5 0 days   2015-01-06
6 2015-01-07               6 2 days   2015-01-09
7 2015-01-08               7 1 days   2015-01-09
8 2015-01-09               8 0 days   2015-01-09
9 2015-01-10               9 2 days   2015-01-12
```

You can iteratively do it on the same column, I just used different columns for each step for easier understanding...

**EDIT for comment**

I guess, that your column PAS_DATE is of dtype=object, although your entries are of dtype=np.datetime[64]. There are some strong reasons, why this should be avoided.

I once had this situation myself for a very long DataFrame and until I figured it out I went through hell. There were all kinds of exceptions, I spend endless hours here on Stackoverflow trying to solve my problems. Also, everything was quite slow and most important, the memory demands for saving the df where very big.

What is going on. Your column is of dtype=object, which means, it only holds pointers to a large collection of datetime object. If it were of dtype=np.datetime[64], it would simply hold the 64bit of datetime information.

Try looking at the info, it should something look like this:

```
print df.info()

Output:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
PAS_DATE          10 non-null datetime64[ns]
dt_since_first    10 non-null int64
shift             10 non-null timedelta64[ns]
for_group_by      10 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(1), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 400.0 bytes
```

Now to convert your PAS_DATE column, try this method:

```
df.PAS_DATE = df.PAS_DATE.convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')
```

You, by the way, should do this as soon as possible in your code. And should probably do it to your other date columns as well. Do df.info() before and after conversion. Tell us, what the difference between the Memory usage is.

Comment: This isn't an issue with your code.  Panda's is a great way to handle something like this, but its still iterating.

The iteration is now being done in the pandas package, in order to map the data into an indexed dataframe.  

The idea of doing it "without iteration" is fundamentally flawed.  At some point the data set has to be split into rows, and each row has to be evaluated in some way, whether by their actual content or by their metadata in relation to other rows.

Comment: @tlastowka You are right, of course. Simply because the same operations are done multiple times (literally **for each** row), there will definitely be loops. Actually a couple of them, because my code needs to iterate multiple times over the dataframe. Nevertheless, this is now vectorized and numpy is doing the operations in a highly optimized fashion. I guess it is faster, but also needs more memory.